Types of parameters 'event' and 'payload' are incompatible
When I run the build command I get the following type error:

Type error: Type '(event: React.FormEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormSubmitHandler'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'payload' are incompatible.
Type '{ data: FieldValues; event?: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined; formData: FormData; formDataJson: string; method?: "delete" | "post" | "put" | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FormEvent': nativeEvent, currentTarget, target, bubbles, and 11 more**.

80 |   };
  81 |   return (
> 82 |     <Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className='contact-form'>
     |           ^
  83 |       {errorMsg && <p className='errorMsg'>{errorMsg}</p>}
  84 |       <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>

Here is the code:
const handleOnSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { email } = contact;
  if (email.trim() === "") {
    setErrorMsg("All the fields are required.");
    return;
  }

  if (!dataToEdit) {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_CONTACT",
      payload: {
        id: Date.now(), // returns current timestamp
        ...contact,
      },
    });
    setContact({
      email: "",
      // lastName: '',
      // phone: ''
    });
    setErrorMsg("");
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_CONTACT",
      payload: {
        id: dataToEdit.id,
        updates: {
          id: Date.now(),
          ...contact,
        },
      },
    });
    toggleModal();
  }
};

<Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className="contact-form">
  {errorMsg && <p className="errorMsg">{errorMsg}</p>}
  <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
  <TextField
    className="email"
    name="email"
    value={contact.email}
    type="text"
    onChange={handleOnChange}
  />
  <Button variant="contained" type="submit" className="submit-btn">
    {dataToEdit ? "Update Contact" : "Add Contact"}
  </Button>
</Form>


What does handleOnSubmit function look like? please update your question and add that function.

@MHDAlaaAlhaj added above.

What's the definition of Form?

I have the code for the form.

I think you are using a ready-made component for the <Form>, what is that library/package you are using?

I have changed to  , and it has worked now.

There was type with  tag. Changed  to  and it has worked.
return (
from
 
to

